# TestDriven.NET Personal version vs Professional Version

Tags: .net, testdriven.net

I'm having trouble finding online resources on the **feature differences** between the Personal version and Profession version TestDriven.NET.

Below is the download link

http://www.testdriven.net/download.aspx

For example what features that Professional version offers but not in the Personal version? Can anybody points me to the correct direction?

Answer (score 2):

No differences except legal issue:

Personnal edition is "For students, open source developers and trial users."

Quoted from this page: http://www.testdriven.net/download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should also notice that the Personal version's license terms do **not** prohibit commercial use; it is just that the author has **requested** commercial users to purchase a license. See http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/comments/456146.aspx for reference.